# What are the double angle trig formulas called?

Tags: trigonometry

For example, what is $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$ called? Here are a few names I can think of:

- Double angle formula for sin
- Double angle formula of sin
- Sin double angle formula
- Double angle sin formula

However, none of these sound "right." Do they have proper names?

Comment: I've learned it under the name double angle formula, but I doubt if there is a proper name for them

Comment: I call them the special cases of the Chebyshev polynomials.  Particularly the second kind for $\sin$, first kind for $\cos$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Chebyshev polynomials are polynomials though, correct? These are equations so not even functions like the Chebyshev polynomials

Comment: @WillFisher Here we have $n=2$.$$\sin(x)U_{n-1}(\cos(x))=\sin(nx)$$

Comment: @WillFisher Oh, I see your confusion.  They are called polynomials because they are polynomials of $\cos$.  For example, $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\implies T_2(x)=2x^2-1$.

Comment: Duplication formulae is another name.

Comment: I meant the name for *specifically* $\sin (2x)$. Maybe I wasn't clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

They are called double angle formulas. It doesn't only work for sine, there's also cosine and tangent, so in general they are called double angle formulas.